# Python SocketIO_client fail ImportError: No module named socketIO_client

Tags: python, socket.io

I installed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client to send messages to volumio API. 
My python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 3000)
socketIO.emit('play')
```

I get this error :

```
 volumio@volumio:/home/FTP$ sudo python volumio-testSocket.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "volumio-testSocket.py", line 3, in <module>
        from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
    ImportError: No module named socketIO_client
```

But my script is working when I run in terminal :

```
volumio@volumio:/home/FTP$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
>>> socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 3000)
>>> socketIO.emit('play')
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed socketIO-client using `pip install -U socketIO-client --user` so it works when I'm calling python and not "sudo python".

I needed sudo to work with gpio so I reinstalled it using `sudo pip install -U socketIO-client` this time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but if you have more than one version of Python installed on your system, the terminal version of Python may be linked to a different version to the one that is trying to run the script from the file. Therefore, one of the versions could have the module installed and the other might not.

That might be worth a look.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I might have other versions of Python installed but the script uses the same version of Python. print (sys.version) -> 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04)
[GCC 4.9.2]