# Installing python-socketio-client

Tags: python, python-socketio

Please excuse my lack of knowledge and poor terminology.
I am trying to get python-socketio-client running on my PI3B. It is used by some python code, not written by me, that takes selected data from Volumio3.x's API (under Buster), and passes it to my audio preamp controller to display it. The current Artist and Song Title.
It all worked on my PI2B with a version of Volumio 2.x under Jessie.

All my attempts to install python-socketio-client have errored.
I was wondering if I should install it with python3, and if so how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To install python packages usually you have to run `pip install -m package-name`

For Volumio if you check documentation (`pyvolumio` package) is this the one you are trying to use?

Only `Python 3.7 and above are supported.`

As you can see in: https://pypi.org/project/pyvolumio/

Comment: Thanks for the reply/suggestion. I hadn't come across pyvolumio so no, it wasn't what I was using. `sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install python-SocketIO-client` Is what I was trying but Python was 2.7.16 and pip 18.1. I have since loaded Python 3.7.3 and pip3.

Comment: Still struggling despite getting "Successfully installed certifi-2021.10.8 chardet-4.0.0 gevent-21.12.0 greenlet-1.1.2 idna-2.10 python-engineio-client-1.1 python-socketio-client-1.1 requests-2.27.1 urllib3-1.26.8 zope.event-4.5.0 zope.interface-5.4.0" when my python code executes "From socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace" I get "ImportError: No module named socketIO_client" Puzzled ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42014584/11381650 check it